# Can't create a Parse object

Tags: parse-platform

Here's a background job I've created to get JSON from a Google Sheet, parse it, create Parse objects, and then save those to my Parse Core.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("importPlaylists", function(request, status) {

    // Use master key
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    // ID of the Google Spreadsheet
    var spreadsheetID = "someId";
    var sheetID = "anotherId";

    var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/" + sheetID + "/public/values?alt=json"; 



    // Cloud function
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {

      // Parse response
      var json = JSON.parse(httpResponse.buffer);

      // Array to store new objects
      var playlistsToSave = [];

      // Create playlist objects
      for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {

        var each = json.feed.entry[i];

        var name = each["gsx$name"]["$t"];
        var playlistid = each["gsx$playlistid"]["$t"];
        var description = each["gsx$description"]["$t"];
        var imageurl = each["gsx$imageurl"]["$t"];
        var categories = each["gsx$categories"]["$t"].split(','); 


        // -- Logs
        console.log('name = ' + name);
        console.log('playlistid = ' + playlistid);
        console.log('description = ' + description);
        console.log('imageurl = ' + imageurl);


        // Create Parse objects 
        var Playlist = Parse.Object.extend("Playlist");
        var playlist = new Playlist();
        playlist.set("name", name);
        playlist.set("playlistid", playlistid);
        playlist.set("description", description);
        playlist.set("imageurl", imageurl);
        playlist.set("categories", categories);

        // -- Logs
        console.log(playlist.playlistid);

        // Add to caching array
        playlistsToSave.push(playlist);



      }


console.log('playlistsToSave = ');
console.log(playlistsToSave);


      // Parse - Save objects
      Parse.Object.saveAll(playlistsToSave, {
        success: function(saveList) {
            status.success("Objects created successfully.");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Unable to save objects.");
        }
      });


    },function(httpResponse) {
      // error
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);

      status.error("Scheduled messages error: " + error);
    });

});
```

The JSON is returning fine. The problem is that when I try to create the new Parse objects they don't seem to be created.

Logging out:

```
    console.log(playlist.playlistid);
```

Returns:

```
I2015-06-11T06:11:21.235Z]No Message provided
```

Also, logging:

```
 console.log('playlistsToSave = ');
 console.log(playlistsToSave);
```

returns:

```
I2015-06-11T06:11:21.236Z]playlistsToSave =
```

Comment: for checking if playlist object property keep a value, since it is a Parse object, you should do like this: `console.log(playlist.get("playlistid"));`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logging based on Luca's answer to:

```
console.log(playlist.get("playlistid"));
```

which does print out a value, so the Playlist object is created and the values are getting set. And also:

```
console.log(playlistsToSave.length);
```

Shows a value of `2`.

What's interesting is that I got a success message when doing this and the playlist objects saved to Parse.

Apparently this line:

```
console.log(playlistsToSave);
```

Was causing an error with message in the Cloud Logs of:

```
Failed with: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.
```

Why? I don't know. So my debug logging was wrong to start with and throwing me off, but trying to log out that array also caused an exception. I come from an objective-c background so logging out an array like that would print the array objects.